# How to add a number variable to an object in a different variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var count = 0;
var price = req.body.price + count;
```

In the above example I want the variable *price* to be equal to **req.body.price0**. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
var price = req.body['price' + count];
```

should do the job

See also [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for more information about that

Comment: Yup, this did it. Thank you very much.